# Crontab won't launch Node.js Discord bot on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, bash, cron, discord.js

I have a bot running on an Ubuntu machine which I'd like to autorun on boot, and so I'm using `crontab`'s `@reboot` scheduled line for it:

`@reboot ~/Bot/run`

It works perfectly for all other scripts I have running on boot on my machine, but for this specific script, every line is seemingly being executed correctly, except for the one involving the actual `node .` command, which launches my Discord bot. The script works perfectly fine when I run it myself from a terminal. Here's the script in question, `run.sh`, very simple and short in nature:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/Bot

echo "Launching Discord Bot"
screen -dmS BOT node .
```

To sum it up, I first enter the correct working directory, send a basic `echo`, then create a new detached screen session called BOT, to which I pass the `node .` command, in which the period `.` implies the `index.js` file found in my bot's directory. And yes, I intend the screen session to automatically close if/when the bot's process stops.

As mentioned, it seems to actually run the script as intended, but just failing to launch the `node.js` server. I've tried adding other test lines to the script, including one that sends a message to said Discord server using a webhook, and it correctly sends the messages when placed before and after the `node .` line.

I've been troubleshooting this for a little while, and I've tried adding a task as a system service in `/etc/systemd/system` instead of using Crontab, to no avail. I've also tried setting the cronjob to use a login shell with `bash -lc` to set the proper environment variables for Crontab, still to no avail. I'm all out of solutions, would anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the point in using `screen` in a crontab-script? `screen`, by its nature, requires an interactive context (at least a terminal it can write to), while a program run from crontab does not have one. You should have gotten on stderr some error message because of this; did you check the error log?

Comment: Have you tried to use systemd?

Comment: I’m using `screen` to launch the bot process in a separate terminal which I can access (attach) and send back to the background (detach). It’s working properly to launch and run my dedicated Minecraft Bedrock servers, which are also scheduled in Crontab. By using `screen -dmS`, I’m effectively creating a new screen session (which can be done from anywhere), detaching from it (leaving it in the background), and naming it BOT. The issue isn’t with the screen aspect, as it indeed creates the screen and runs any other command, but fails to run the `node .` command, leaving the screen “dead”.

Comment: And yes, as mentioned, I have tried using a `systemd` service, with the same result.

Comment: Can you show me the service file?

Comment: better of to just use the `pm2` npm package a lot bette than other approaches

Comment: Could you briefly explain what the advantages are with `pm2`?

Comment: Recommendations: Avoid `cron` and `crontab` (flawed and deprecated stuff). Use `systemd` units for proper presence tracking, failure / retry handling, resource bookkeeping, log management, dependency resolution, security hardening and more. You say you _tried_ adding a `systemd` unit: what did `journalctl -u your_unit.service` say? Why do you use `screen` instead of letting `systemd-journald` do the logging? (BTW, to use `screen` with `systemd`, you need `systemd-run --scope --user screen` — or search `logind.conf`, `KillUserProcesses`, `KillExcludeUsers`.) **Never** run daemons under `root`.